# Json string cutsoff after # symbol in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

am using AngularJs service to call my MVC controller method and sending parameters along with it. this is my angular service Url and model

```
var transData = {
    Address: $scope.user.address,
    Comments: $scope.user.comments,
    Password: $scope.password,
    Id: $scope.id
};`
```

`'../transaction/UpdateData?transModelData=' + angular.toJson(transData)`

this is my MVC Action method

`public void UpdateData(string transModelData = null)`

My problem is occuring when i use special character **#** in my password field.

Json string is cuts off after the password like below

`{"Address":"address","Password":"qwerty123`

but the actual json string should be like

`{"Address":"address","Password":"qwerty123#","StudentId":"12"}`

can anyone help me out to overcome this issue, thanks

Comment: have you tried html encoding the values before putting it into json?

Comment: Nope i didn't, is it necessary?

Comment: shouldn't be, but it will encode the offending character, and you can then decode it back on the other end

Comment: how to do html encoding? i didnt try before? any references please...